# Bluetooth LE on Windows 10 throws exception 0x80070572 on second connection attempt

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10-universal

I am using the Bluetooth Low Energy API on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 to connect to a custom Bluetooth LE device. I have to pair the device with Windows before connecting to it through my code, and it all works on Windows 8.1, and partially works on Windows 10, because on Windows 10 I have to unpair the device and pair it again in order to get it working. On Windows 10, if I try to connect to the device a second time, I get the following exception:

'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll There is no user session key for the specified logon session. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070572)

I believe this might be because my external Bluetooth device isn't storing bonding information - but this doesn't explain why it works on Windows 8.1 without a problem, I'm not sure if the way the PC handles Bluetooth changed drastically between those two versions. Does anyone know a way around this exception, or what I can do?

Comment: What's the version of your Windows 10? What's the status of your Bluetooth LE device in Setting App before you **have to unpair the device and pair it again in order to get it working** , paired or connected?

Comment: @RitaHan I am on the latest version of Windows 10. The status of the Bluetooth LE device in the settings app is "Paired", when I try to connect to it using await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync or DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync() after it is "Paired" I get the exception.